# Java KeyListener "object update"

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I've got a `KeyListener` class called `Keyboard` which implements `KeyListener`'s methods.

There are 4 states keys can have with it (`UP, ISUP, DOWN, ISDOWN`) all representing whether they're down, or they just became down.

Before every update to the `Keyboard`, I'd like to change all of the `UP`s to `ISUPS`, and `DOWN`s to `ISDOWN`s.

There is an `Update` method on the Keyboard class, but I don't know when to call it (because the `addKeyListener()` function seems to be magic and just works without having to call any functions [probably launches a thread])

How do I know when to call the `Update` method? (right before the `Keyboard` is about to fire events)

Here's the `Keyboard` class itself:

```
package game.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

enum KeyStatus
{
    DOWN, ISDOWN, UP, ISUP
}

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener
{
    private Map<Character, KeyStatus> keys;

    public Keyboard()
    {
        keys = new HashMap<Character, KeyStatus>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            keys.put((char)i, KeyStatus.ISUP);
        }
    }

    public void update() //This should be called after every event loop (how?)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<Character, KeyStatus> ks: keys.entrySet())
        {
            if (ks.getValue() == KeyStatus.UP)
                keys.put(ks.getKey(), KeyStatus.ISUP);

            else if (ks.getValue() == KeyStatus.DOWN)
                keys.put(ks.getKey(), KeyStatus.ISDOWN);
        }
    }

    public boolean keyDown(char i)
    {
        return (keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.DOWN || keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.ISDOWN);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(char i)
    {
        return (keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.DOWN);
    }

    public boolean keyUp(char i)
    {
        return (keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.UP || keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.ISUP);
    }

    public boolean onKeyUp(char i)
    {
        return (keys.get(i) == KeyStatus.UP);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key)
    {
        keys.put(key.getKeyChar(), KeyStatus.DOWN);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key)
    {
        keys.put(key.getKeyChar(), KeyStatus.UP);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand your UP and DOWN states, but what do ISUP and ISDOWN represent? They appear to be redundant. Also, have you read up on key bindings which may be better options than a KeyListener?

Comment: @Hovercraftfullofeels UP, DOWN = User JUST pushed the key. ISUP, ISDOWN = The key is currently down.

Comment: What you call UP, DOWN above then are not states but rather events. I fear that your structure is broken. What you desire is two states, what I'd call UP and DOWN, and indicating whether the key is currently up or down. You then would *listen* for events where the state changes. But you don't make the event a state.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Whilst this would make sense normally, I'm writing a game. Not every component can have access to the `KeyListener`. Is this not the right way to do it? (Store the current state of the keys in an array, and when you get a DOWN event, change the key in the array? [to DOWN, then after one loop to ISDOWN])

Comment: OK, answer this, how long is your UP state supposed to last? When is it supposed to change from UP to ISUP and by what mechanism? What sort of Timer are you using? The answer is, it is moot. Again, your logic and structure are faulty. What you suggest is not the right way to do it, not by any means. In fact your whole problem currently is that you *don't* have this mechanism, and in fact you don't need it or want it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels UP state lasts one event loop. Like this: Update input state, update game elements, render game elements, update the input state again (changing all UPs to ISUPs)

By what method do you suggest I get key input?

Comment: "one event loop", makes no sense. If you're listening for changes in a key's state, up or down, and you're listening to a sub-set of the keys (for instance arrow keys, space bar) then use key bindings. You still need to learn the difference though between event and state. You've got it wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29569/discussion-between-superdisk-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyListener` is registered to a component, which is notified by the `EventQueue` when a `KeyEvent` of some kind occurs.  The `EventQueue` is notified by a platform specific mechanism which is tied directly to the OS/native layer.

Swing generally uses an [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) when it comes to listeners.  That is, you attach a listener to a component which will tell you when something happens

You shouldn't "need" to call any method to check the state of the keys.  Instead, when a `KeyEvent` is triggered, the `KeyListener` will be notified (via the event chain) and fire an appropriate event through the `KeyListener` interface.

A `KeyListener` needs to be registered with some component that is visible on the screen, can obtain keyboard focus and has focus at the time the event occurred.

Take a look at [How to write Key Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for more details.

You may also find [Introduction to Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) useful.

`KeyListener` suffers from focus issues (only the currently focusable/focused component can receive `KeyEvents`).  It is recommend that you use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

**Updated**

After a round robin of disscussion where we nutted out what was the real problem, we concluded that the OP was trying to generate a masking list of keys that were currently pressed, but had been processed by the game engine, in an effort to eliminate the key-repeat from triggering more updates.

We came to the conclusion that the OP should generate a "processed" and "active" list of keys.

When a key pressed event is triggered, the keyboard handler would check to see if the key exists on in the "processed" list, if it does, the key is ignored, otherwise it is placed in the active list.

When the game engine processes the keys, it scans the "active" list, takes action and places each key on the "processed" list.

Once the key is released, it is removed from the processed list.

Comment: I've got all of this stuff down, that's not my problem. I'm just trying to update the state of my key array to represent how long the keys have been down (UP and DOWN for when they've just been pushed, ISUP and ISDOWN for if they are currently down.)

Comment: @Mad: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29569/discussion-between-superdisk-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)